# How to append a sublist to a dataframe in a specific index and column based on an element in the sublist?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a nested list that is randomly generated shown below

```
[[[6008, 'BSC3', 'ST1'], ['LB1'], ['MTM2']], [[5227, 'BSC2', 'ST8'], ['LB1'], ['TTM1']]]
```

I also have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image: Empty Schedule]

**My question is how do I fill a specific slot inside the timetable for every of the sublist generated above based on the element in each of those sublist?** For example, inside the nested list the first sublist is:

```
[[6008, 'BSC3', 'ST1'], ['LB1'], ['MTM2']]
```

The 2 element of that list has 'MTM2' which represents Monday and timeslot #2 (which is 12:00PM - 2:00PM).

Second sublist

```
[[5227, 'BSC2', 'ST8'], ['LB1'], ['TTM1']]
```

and the second element is 'TTM1' which represents Tuesday and timeslot #1 (which is 9:30AM - 12:30PM)

My expectation for the example above, is that the dataframe will look something like this:

[image]

This is my test attempt (which has no effect):

```
 def append_to_timetable(self, solution):

        for x in solution:

            if x[2] == 'MTM1':
                self.m.loc['Monday', 0] = x
                print(self.m)

        return self.m
```

EDIT: Added 13 more sublists (now a total of 15 sublist)

```
[[[4220, 'BSC2', 'ST5'], ['CR1'], ['THTM2']], [[4201, 'BSC1', 'ST1'], ['LB1'], ['TTM3']], [[4222, 'BSC1', 'ST6'], ['CR1'], ['THTM2']], [[6226, 'BSC3', 'ST6'], ['LB1'], ['THTM3']], [[4220, 'BSC2', 'ST5'], ['LH1'], ['WTM1']], [[4227, 'BSC1', 'ST4'], ['LB1'], ['MTM2']], [[5225, 'BSC2', 'ST6'], ['LR1'], ['TTM3']], [[4227, 'BSC1', 'ST4'], ['LH2'], ['FTM1']], [[6224, 'BSC1', 'ST4'], ['LH1'], ['FTM3']], [[3225, 'BSC1', 'ST6'], ['LR1'], ['WTM2']], [[6224, 'BSC1', 'ST4'], ['LB1'], ['THTM1']], [[4220, 'BSC2', 'ST5'], ['LH2'], ['WTM2']], [[4210, 'BSC1', 'ST1'], ['LH2'], ['THTM2']], [[6224, 'BSC1', 'ST4'], ['LR1'], ['TTM3']], [[5227, 'BSC2', 'ST8'], ['LH1'], ['WTM1']]]
```

also wondering, is it possible to insert two or more sublists into the same specific slot? for example:

```
[[5225, 'BSC2', 'ST6'], ['LR1'], ['TTM3']]

and 

[[4201, 'BSC1', 'ST1'], ['LB1'], ['TTM3']]
```

are at the same time. It would look like this:

[image]

Comment: What is the encoding for Thursday? Same question for Saturday and Sunday if needed

Comment: The encoding for Thursday is 'TH'. It would be 'THTM1', 'THTM2', and 'THTM3'. None  for Saturday and Sunday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

After your edit, the situation is a bit more complicated but the idea remains the same:

```
cols = {'M': 'Monday', 'T': 'Tuesday', 'W': 'Wednesday',
        'TH': 'Thursday', 'F': 'Friday'}
rows = df.index.tolist()

def get_loc(code):
    m, t = code.split('TM')
    col = cols[m]
    row = rows[int(t) - 1]
    return (row, col)

# Decode each element of the list
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuple(get_loc(x[2][0]) for x in l), 
                               names=['row', 'col'])

out = pd.Series([l]).explode().to_frame('data').set_index(mi).reset_index() \
        .pivot_table('data', 'row', 'col', aggfunc=list, fill_value='') \
        .reindex(index=df.index, columns=df.columns, fill_value='')
```

Output:

|  | Monday | Thuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **9:30AM - 12:30PM** |  |  | [[[4220, 'BSC2', 'ST5'], ['LH1'], ['WTM1']], [[5227, 'BSC2', 'ST8'], ['LH1'], ['WTM1']]] | [[[6224, 'BSC1', 'ST4'], ['LB1'], ['THTM1']]] | [[[4227, 'BSC1', 'ST4'], ['LH2'], ['FTM1']]] |
| **12:00PM - 2:00PM** | [[[4227, 'BSC1', 'ST4'], ['LB1'], ['MTM2']]] |  | [[[3225, 'BSC1', 'ST6'], ['LR1'], ['WTM2']], [[4220, 'BSC2', 'ST5'], ['LH2'], ['WTM2']]] | [[[4220, 'BSC2', 'ST5'], ['CR1'], ['THTM2']], [[4222, 'BSC1', 'ST6'], ['CR1'], ['THTM2']], [[4210, 'BSC1', 'ST1'], ['LH2'], ['THTM2']]] |  |
| **2:00PM - 5:00PM** |  |  |  | [[[6226, 'BSC3', 'ST6'], ['LB1'], ['THTM3']]] | [[[6224, 'BSC1', 'ST4'], ['LH1'], ['FTM3']]] |

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Monday', 'Thuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
                  index=['9:30AM - 12:30PM', '12:00PM - 2:00PM', '2:00PM - 5:00PM'])

l = [[[4220, 'BSC2', 'ST5'], ['CR1'], ['THTM2']],
    [[4201, 'BSC1', 'ST1'], ['LB1'], ['TTM3']],
    [[4222, 'BSC1', 'ST6'], ['CR1'], ['THTM2']],
    [[6226, 'BSC3', 'ST6'], ['LB1'], ['THTM3']],
    [[4220, 'BSC2', 'ST5'], ['LH1'], ['WTM1']],
    [[4227, 'BSC1', 'ST4'], ['LB1'], ['MTM2']],
    [[5225, 'BSC2', 'ST6'], ['LR1'], ['TTM3']],
    [[4227, 'BSC1', 'ST4'], ['LH2'], ['FTM1']],
    [[6224, 'BSC1', 'ST4'], ['LH1'], ['FTM3']],
    [[3225, 'BSC1', 'ST6'], ['LR1'], ['WTM2']],
    [[6224, 'BSC1', 'ST4'], ['LB1'], ['THTM1']],
    [[4220, 'BSC2', 'ST5'], ['LH2'], ['WTM2']],
    [[4210, 'BSC1', 'ST1'], ['LH2'], ['THTM2']],
    [[6224, 'BSC1', 'ST4'], ['LR1'], ['TTM3']],
    [[5227, 'BSC2', 'ST8'], ['LH1'], ['WTM1']]]
```

---

**Old answer**

You can use a function to decode the index and the columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Monday', 'Thuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
                  index=['9:30AM - 12:30PM', '12:00PM - 2:00PM', '2:00PM - 5:00PM'])

l = [[[6008, 'BSC3', 'ST1'], ['LB1'], ['MTM2']],
     [[5227, 'BSC2', 'ST8'], ['LB1'], ['TTM1']]]

# Check for Thursday encoding?
day_to_col = {'M': 0, 'T': 1, 'W': 2, 'TH': 3, 'F': 4}

def get_loc(code):
    m, t = code.split('TM')
    col = day_to_col[m]
    row = int(t) - 1
    return (row, col)

df.to_numpy()[tuple(get_loc(x[2][0]) for x in l)] = l
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                              Monday                            Thuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday
9:30AM - 12:30PM                                 NaN  [[5227, BSC2, ST8], [LB1], [TTM1]]       NaN      NaN    NaN
12:00PM - 2:00PM  [[6008, BSC3, ST1], [LB1], [MTM2]]                                 NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN
2:00PM - 5:00PM                                  NaN                                 NaN       NaN      NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Note: you can use `return row, col` instead of `return (row, col)` (pure preference; do what you'd like)

Comment: Assigning to `.to_numpy()`: smart! I was baffled on how to get the lists in the DF.

Comment: **The Zen of Python**: *Explicit is better than implicit.* (line 2). looool

Comment: You're right, but I believe it's standard Python convention to omit the parentheses when returing a tuple. Also, you're not doing it with `(m, t) = code.split('TM')`... ;)

Comment: You got me. lol. Seriously, I'm really surprised to have to use numpy to do the assignment...

Comment: It's a neat trick though. I'm surprised that assigning to the result of a function call (although you're not *exactly*; you're assigning to the result of *indexing* the result of a function call) even works at all.

Comment: What I meant is I can't use `.iloc` to do the same thing and I don't know how to do that without numpy (`.to_numpy()` or `.values`)

Comment: I understand; I was experimenting with this question as well and discovered the same. I didn't to use `to_numpy()` - I would've come up with a much more gnarly and ugly solution :P